# Spring Jpa Pageable get content using Java stream

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8

I am doing a search to bring all registered cars 100 by 100 in a paginated way.

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 100);
Page<Car> listOfcars = carService.findAll(pageable);
```

For me to get to the next page, I'm doing it via while:

```
while(listOfcars.hasNext()){
   listOfcars = carService.findAll(listOfcars.nextPageable());
   carService.start(listOfcars.getContent());
   log.info("New batch sent" + listOfcars.getTotalElements());
}
```

There is a way to do this via the java stream, searching for the data on a page and right after that already searching for the sequences without having to do it via while ?

Comment: Don't understand what you want to say. Try to clear your post once again.

Answer (score 0):

you can try by knowing total of available pages (maybe a total count will be needed first) and store each page numeric representation in a collection (let's say pages = [1, 2, ... n] ) then you can create a method OperateListOfCars and call your logic for each page with pages.stream()... maybe create a CustomPageResult wrapper and put there the pages collection will help to have the code more clean.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need stream or loop here, you can use [getContent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Slice.html#getContent--) method to return all content in a List from [Page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html)

> Returns the page content as List.

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 100);
Page<Car> listOfcars = carService.findAll(pageable);
List<Car> cars = listOfCars.getContent();
```